# 1.33.0 cardano-cli query stake-snapshot does not generate json

Tags: cardano-cli, stake-pool

I'm trying to generate leaderlogs on cardano-node 1.33.0

when i try to query the stake snapshot with

`cardano-cli query stake-snapshot --stake-pool-id 3bd3996595321d951291b11e1331061c5d8659d9e69390536dfc922c --mainnet`

it does not generate a json file but wired output

```
86  # list(6)
   19 01 3b  # int(315)
   b9 04 51  # map(1105)
       # key
      58 1c 00 00 00 36 d5 15 e1 2e 18 cd 3c 88 c7 4f
      09 a6 79 84 c2 c2 79 a5 29 6a a9 6e fe 89  # bytes(28)
       # value
      18 41  # int(65)
       # key
      58 1c 00 00 00 f6 6e 28 b0 f1 8a ef 20 55 5f 4c
      49 54 23 4e 32 70 df bb dc c1 3f 54 e7 99  # bytes(28)
       # value
      18 3b  # int(59)
       # key
      58 1c 00 00 01 10 09 3e ff bf 3c e7 88 ae bd 3e
      75 06 b8 03 22 bd 39 95 ad 43 2e 61 fa d5  # bytes(28)
       # value
      0b  # int(11)
       # key
      58 1c 00 00 01 b8 44 f4 e4 c9 00 ae 0d fd c8 4a
      88 45 f7 10 90 b8 2f b4 73 e6 c7 0a 31 ee  # bytes(28)
       # value
      18 1b  # int(27)
       # key
      58 1c 00 00 06 6c 3b 2b 15 f7 ae ce 35 5a 11 2e
      f1 41 e9 fe 84 d2 e2 15 2d 43 98 98 6e 40  # bytes(28)
       # value
      01  # int(1)
```

and therefore `jq .poolStakeMark <<< $SNAPSHOT` fails

Did the output of the command change?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user solved their problem already.

Comment: This is not a helpdesk.  It is intended to be a library of solutions that others can refer to for quite some time to come.  Solving the problem doesn't mean it should be closed.  Please take a look at the [tour] and [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems the problem was that i used an older cardano-cli with a newer cardano-node